# NodeJs geo near issue when query from latitude and longitude

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geolocation

What is the matter from this code? i have error that i cannot resolve :

```
var d = [
        {
           $geoNear: {
              near : {
                type: 'Point',
                coordinates: [48.3816034, 2.9288093]
              },
              distanceField: 'distance',
              minDistance:0,
              maxDistance: 20000,
              spherical :true
           }
        }
        ,
        {"$lookup":
           {"from":"users","localField":"userId","foreignField":"_id","as":"volontaire"}
        }
     ]

 UserProfile.aggregate(d, (err, results) => console.log(results) )
```

Where my Model is designed like this :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   userId:{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
   loc: {
       type: [Number], // [<longitude>, <latitude>]
      index: "2d" // create the geospatial index
   },
});

var UserProfile = mongoose.model('UserProfile', UserSchema);
module.exports = UserProfile;
```

The query error output is :

```
{"name":"MongoError","message":"geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"error processing query: ns=Lab.userprofiles limit=100Tree: GEONEAR  field=loc maxdist=20000 isNearSphere=1\nSort: {}\nProj: { $pt: { $meta: \"geoNearPoin...\", code: 2, codeName: \"BadValue\" }","ok":0,"errmsg":"geoNear command failed: { ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"error processing query: ns=Lab.userprofiles limit=100Tree: GEONEAR  field=loc maxdist=20000 isNearSphere=1\nSort: {}\nProj: { $pt: { $meta: \"geoNearPoin...\", code: 2, codeName: \"BadValue\" }","code":16604,"codeName":"Location16604"
```

Someone could helps me please? i don't understand where is this "BAD VALUE"

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure but you should try with promise instead of callback here... Or if not then please show how you made your db connection

Comment: Hi, 
I have similar query inside another controller that is working fine : 
this how i made a connection to the model : 
const UserProfile = require('../models/UserProfile');